# Получение данных из изменяющегося массива

Tags: javascript, vue3

Есть такой код:

```
function findIndexOfMinLow(array, startIndex, posLow) {
  let minLow = Infinity;
  let minLowIndex = -1;

  let arrayLength;

  if(array.length < candlesChartQuantity.value){
    arrayLength = array.length;
  } else if(posLow !== 'second'){
    arrayLength = array.length-1;
  } else {
    arrayLength = array.length;
  }

  if(posLow === 'second'){

    for (let i = startIndex; i < arrayLength; i++) {

      const lowValue = array[i].low;

      if(activeTimeframe.value.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
       console.log(array, array[i].low, i);
      }

      if (!isNaN(lowValue) && lowValue < minLow) {
        minLow = lowValue;
        minLowIndex = i;
      }
    }
  }

  return minLowIndex;
}
```

В результате которого мы получаем следующий вывод в консоли:

```
Proxy(Array) {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
[[Handler]]
: 
Object
[[Target]]
: 
Array(3)
0
: 
{_id: 0, ticker: 'EURUSD', open: 1.12161, high: 1.12314, low: 1.12154, …}
1
: 
{_id: 1, ticker: 'EURUSD', open: 1.12232, high: 1.12262, low: 1.12099, …}
2
: 
{_id: 2, ticker: 'EURUSD', open: 1.12141, high: 1.12178, low: 1.12141, …}
length
: 
3
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]
: 
false

1.12085 2
```

Обращаем внимание на значение `low` 2-го елемента массива которое внутри массива равно `1.12141`.
При попытке взять это значение из данного массива как мы можем пронаблюдать мы получаем совсем другое число `1.12085`.

Из того что я понимаю такое поведение происходит по причине того, что на лету данный массив изменяет свое значение 2-го елемента с `1.12085` на `1.12141`.
И каким то образом само св-во массива во время извлечения способно извлечь только лишь старую копию массива.
Если делать глубокую копию массива предварительно внутри начала этой функции - то внутри данного массива - 2-й елемент `low` будет равен `1.12085` как внутри массива так и при его извлечении.

Вопрос:
Почему происходит разница в выводе в консоли общего массива и внутреннего елемента?
Как вытащить обновленное значение `1.12141` из массива?

Comment: В функции выше, я не вижу изменения данных. Покажите исходный массив, как и где он меняется и когда данные выводятся. В вашем примере 1 console.log(), а судя по выводу, их больше. И если данные меняются быстро, то каждый браузере волен показывать то, что считает нужным(если правильно помню, хром отображает вообще ссылкой объекты, а не копией на момент вывода).

Comment: там слишком сложно все если массив весь показывать и обьяснять его работу.
Ну да ладно - спасибо за ответ в любом случае.
Суть вопроса была в том что если консоль отлавливает изменения прокси - можно ли с емитировать такой же анализ полученного св-ва массива и этим действием получить обновленный елемент.